# Null property in object recovered by EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm having trouble pulling a `ApplicationUser` object in a query to the `DbContext`.

Here is my `Foo` model

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Inside of my Foo controller in the edit action I want to check that the User requesting the edit is the Creator.

```
//ApplicationDbContext inherits IdentityDbContext
private ApplicationDbContext appDb { get; set; }
...
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
        Foo target =  appDb.Foos.First(o => o.Id == id);

        if (target == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (target.Creator.Id != User.Identity.GetUserId())
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Permission denied.";
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }

        return View(target);
    }
```

The problem is that for some reason `target.Creator` returns null, although all `Foo` have a `Creator` object referenced. In the same controller, in the details action it gets pulled just fine:

```
var entry = appDb.Foos.Where(f=>f.Id == id)
            .Select(foo => new FooViewModel()
            {
                Id = foo.Id,
                Title = foo.Title,
                CreatorId = foo.Creator.Id,
                CreatorName = foo.Creator.FirstName,
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

What am I missing? What is so different about trying to access `foo.Creator` inside of the Display query than trying to access it directly on a Foo object? I thought EF would have queried for `foo.Creator` when I requested the Foo itself.

Should I change `foo.Creator` to store `foo.CreatorId` instead?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to `Include` the `Creator` related to the `Foo` explicitly, I believe.

Comment: more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need eager loading -

```
var returned = appDb.Foos.First(o => o.Id == id).Include(a => a.Creator);
```

On the other hand, you could use `Lazy Loading` by marking the `ApplicationUser` member as virtual.

Comment: Lazy Loading! That's what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: please accept as an answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The navigation properties are not feched by default. If you need them, eager load them using `.Include()`:

```
Foo target =  appDb.Foos.First(o => o.Id == id).Include(f => f.Creator);
```

Your code will not work at all: if you try to find the first element, with `.First()` and it doesn't exist, you'll get an exception. I.e, your code will never hit `if (target == null)`.

You should use `.FirstOrDefault()`, or better thant that, `Find()`.